# How does JSONRepresentation of NSDictionary class works?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

some time ago I was figuring out JSON handling in Objective-C (iPhone) and I found one confusing thing there.

This call puzzles me:

```
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];
```

In fact `jsonDict` is an instance of `NSDictionary` class and according to [NSDictionary Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) NSDictionary does not have this `JSONRepresentation` method. I feel cheated somewhere, I know that it works but can't figure out how.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of a "Category", which is a way to add methods to existing classes.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [JSON Framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) this method came from.

Comment: yes, I know that I'm using `JSON Framework`, what I don't understand is that I'm sending a message to NSDictionary, how does NSDictionary know how to handle this message - that is my question.

Comment: It's called category. It's used to add methods to existing class without subclassing it.

Answer (score 3):

The framework puts a category on NSDictionary. Categories are used to add extra methods to a class. More info on how categories work an are implemented is in the docs. Now that you know the right term for it it should be easy to find.